# Laravel file validation - how fix "variable is immediately overridden"

Tags: php, laravel

I make project in Laravel. I make this code to validation file size and format:

```
class KnowledgeBaseMovieRequest extends FormRequest
{

    public function authorize()
    {
        return true;
    }

    public function rules()
    {
        $id = $this->route('knowledge_base_movie');

        $rules = [
            'name' => ['required', 'max:255'],
        ];

        if (empty($id)) {
            $rules['movie'] = ['file', 'required', 'max:200000'];
            $rules['movie'] = ['file', 'max:20000', new Mp4File];
        }

        return $rules;
    }

}

class Mp4File implements Rule {

    const MIMES = [
        'video/mp4'
    ];
    const EXT = 'mp4';

    public function passes($attribute, $file) {
        return in_array($file->getClientMimeType(), self::MIMES) && $file->getClientOriginalExtension() === self::EXT;
    }

    public function message() {
        return ':attribute musi być plikiem .mp4.';
    }

}
```

I need file in max size 200000 and in format mp4.

In tjis line:

```
$rules['movie'] = ['file', 'required', 'max:200000'];
$rules['movie'] = ['file', 'max:20000', new Mp4File];
```

I have "$rules['movie'] is immediately overridden"

How can I fix it?

Comment: why are you overwriting the variable you defined on the next line?

Comment: How can I write these 2 conditions in 1 line?;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just group all your rules in one time variable :

```
$rules['movie'] = ['file', 'required', 'max:200000', new Mp4File];
```

Why do you want to have 2 lines for the same index ?